# What should I put in REDASH_REDIS_URL for Redash connect to AWS Redis?

Tags: docker-compose, redis, amazon-rds, aws-fargate, redash

I am trying to configure docker-compose.yml so the Redash docker can connect to my AWS resources. There are two environmental variables I think I should change from default:

```
REDASH_REDIS_URL: "redis://redis:6379/0"
REDASH_DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://postgres@postgres/postgres"
```

My endpoints for Redis & RDS are:
redash-redis.xxxxxx.xx.xxxx.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379
redash-1-instance-1.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com (writer instance)

Is the followings look right before I build the docker image? I want to push to ECR for Fargate to use in task.

```
REDASH_REDIS_URL: "redis://redash-redis.xxxxxx.xx.xxxx.usw2.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/0"
REDASH_DATABASE_URL: "postgresql://redash-1-instance-1.xxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com@postgres/postgres"
```

The ultimate goal is to host Redash, Redis, Postgresql in our AWS environment, connect postgresql & redis in the docker image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your Redis URL is correct but there are some mistakes in your Postgres URL. The following URL worked for us. You should give something like this:

```
REDASH_DATABASE_URL=postgresql://{username}:{password}@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com/postgres
```

Comment: thx for the info. I modified the database environmental variable with {username}:{password} as mentioned. The task still shows "not configured". I think it may have been network issue. I will check the networking of the service/task and come back to this. Making redash work in Fargate is really a pain in the a**.

Comment: I think you need to allow access from port 5432 which is the default for postgresql